# Is it safe to compare C++ iterators by order

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm trying to implement C++'s reverse function as an exercise. The exercise instructions (from Caltech's advanced C++ course) hint that you should use the `distance` function, which counts the number of items between two iterators. Using this hint, I wrote the below function, which appears to work:

```
template <typename BidirectionalIterator>
void my_reverse(BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last) {
    last--; // input "last" is one past the end
    while( first != last && distance(first, last) > 1 ){
        std::swap(*first, *last);
        first++;
        last--;
    }
    return;
}
```

But I have a problem with this approach: if I'm not mistaken, calling `distance` at each step makes this an O(n^2) algorithm.
So I replaced the while condition with the following:

```
    while( first < last ){
```

This also appears to work. But it makes me a little nervous, because the documentation on BidirectionalIterators doesn't guarantee that the iterators can be ordered like this. Can I trust that this ordering will always work as intended, and that `v.end()` will always be greater than `v.begin()` for an STL container object `v`?

(My concern comes from thinking like a Haskell programmer that BidirectionalIterators are guaranteed to have properties of Eq, so to speak, but not Ord.)

Comment: `<` is random access iterator only. You just need to call `distance` once at the start, and then you can use the return value to calculate how many iterations your loop should run. No need to call it at each iteration. Also, look into `std::iter_swap`.

Comment: you can save the value from `distance` and update it in loop `-=2`

Comment: Just saying that your current implementation won't swap the two middle elements for a container with an even number of elements. You probably want to check for `>= 1` instead of `> 1`. Probably you should go with one of the implementations without any `std::distance` calls anyways tho.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and bugfixes, everyone! That >= mistake is pretty embarrassing...I tested it but literally forgot that 7 comes before 8. I reversed a vector with elements (6,7,8,9) and the output was (9,7,8,6) and I thought yep, that looks good. Whoops.

Comment: That algorithm breaks when reversing an empty sequence. It stops when the two iterators are not at least two steps apart, which is the case for direct neighbours, who's elements still need to be swapped. Further, distance() is an O(n) algorithm on some datatypes, making this O(n^2). I believe you can do better, in particularly using a few unittests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bidirectional iterators (which are not also random-access iterators) do not support `operator<`. Try passing `std::list` iterators to your function, and you will see that it fails to compile. The reason they do not support this operation is precisely because it would be very expensive.

As far as using `distance`:

> if I'm not mistaken, calling distance at each step makes this an
>   O(n^2) algorithm.

You are correct<sup>1</sup>. This is not a good way to implement a reverse algorithm. There is no need to get the distance between the iterators. You can do it using just `operator!=` and/or `operator==`, which are both O(1).

<sub>1. Unless you pass random access iterators, in which case distance will use `operator-`, and the algorithm will be O(n), as expected.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I especially like the suggestion to pass std::list iterators--undeniable proof that the approach is broken.

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm has undefined behavior if someone passes an empty range (`first == last`) to it because you decrement `last` before checking for that condition. You need

```
void my_reverse(BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last) {
    while((first != last) && (first != --last)){
        std::swap(*first, *last);
        first++;
    }
    return;
}
```

And instead of deferencing the iterators and calling `std::swap` on the result, you can use [`std::iter_swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap) which does it all for you.

```
void my_reverse(BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last) {
    while((first != last) && (first != --last)){
        std::iter_swap(first, last);
        first++;
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps...

```
void my_reverse(BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last)
{
    while (first != last && --last != first)
    {
        std::swap(*first, *last);
        ++first;
    }
}
```

The thing here is that each swap needs to be done after both incrementing `first` and decrementing `last` (in either order), but the point where they equal each other could be after just one such operation has been performed, so there should be two comparisons that might break from the loop for each `swap` performed.